# vimdiff: show only difference between "base" and "remote"

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I'm merging two branches in a project, which both changed the same part of some files in different ways. The "remote" branch is somewhat closer to the common ancestor ("base"), so I want to only show the differences between "base" and "remote"; by default, all lines different in any two files (I think) are highlighted, leaving a large region of highlighting with little useful information. Can I do this?

It would be better if I can simultaneously show the difference between "base" and "remote", and between "local" and "merged"; essentially, two diff sessions in one vim. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I workaround this issue by using a tmux

1. open a tmux
2. split the tmux horizontally using ctrl-a-double_quote
3. open vimdiffs individually

of course , you have to manage scrolling between the windows yourself - but that is the best shot with native vimdiff.

Comment: I just learned about tmux today, and that's definitely a fine way to do it! I was about to ask how to do this with `git mergetool`, then I realized I can just run `:!tmux` from the vim spawned by the mergetool, and be ready to go :)